# How to zoom in on the actual location of the device?

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, kotlin

I can not zoom in the current location of the device, could someone help me?
any help is welcome.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    Log.i("MAP READY", "READY")
    val position = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else null
    this.map = googleMap
    
    getFineLocationPermission()
    this.map!!.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
    this.map!!.uiSettings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = true
    this.map!!.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
    this.map!!.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this)
    this.map!!.setOnMapLongClickListener(this)


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can change a map's zoom level by changing its camera position. According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#zoom):

> `To change the position of the camera, you must specify where you want to move the camera, using a CameraUpdate. The Maps API allows you to create many different types of CameraUpdate using CameraUpdateFactory.`

Since you did not provide your full code, let me insert samples below:

- If you want to keep all other maps properties to be the same and just change the zoom level, you can use this line:

  ```
  //where zoomLevel is your preferred zoom level
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomLevel))
  ```
- If you want to zoom a map on the location where the marker was placed, then below your `addMarker()` function, you can add this line to zoom your map on a `City` level:

  ```
  // zoomLevel is set at 10 for a City-level view
  val zoomLevel = 10
  // latLng contains the coordinates where the marker is added
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoomLevel))
  ```

  Fun tip: *You can* ***animate*** *the camera view update if you use* `animateCamera()` *instead of using* `moveCamera()`

For more information on Maps SDK for Android - *Camera and View* settings, please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views

Answer (score 0):

Better you can optimize your code

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
Log.i("MAP READY", "READY")
val position = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, 
currentLocation!!.longitude) else null
this.map = googleMap

getFineLocationPermission()
this.map?.let{
it.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
it.uiSettings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = true
it.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
it.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this)
it.setOnMapLongClickListener(this)
//zooming into the map
it.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation,zoomLevel)) 
}
```